# ASP.NET MVC and Ninject - result action with interface parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

kinda new to MVC, and kinda new with Ninject. Playing around...

I've defined ninject in my MVC application as follows:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind(
    x => x.FromThisAssembly()
        .SelectAllClasses()
        .BindAllInterfaces()
        );
}
```

I have controller with a form and this ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Index(IMember Member)
{
    return View();
}
```

and it's returning an error: "Cannot create an instance of an interface."

Now I understand that it might not like the interface but isn't Ninject supposed to inject the real class in there? do I need to put in the actual class? if so, doesn't that take the point out of using interfaces and building a lossly-cuppuled apps?

BTW in my Index.cshtml file I have the following as the first line:

```
@model IMember
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing constructor dependency injection with action method parameters, they are not the same thing.

- In your case you seem to want Ninject to somehow inject a concrete `IMember` implementation whenever a client (browser, etc) calls the `Index` action.
- Bear in mind that any parameters that are going to be passed into an Action method are going to be coming *from the client* and not from the framework, so it wouldn't make sense to do this.
- I am sure there is a hack you could do to make it work for e.g decorate the parameter with `[Inject]` or something but you've already lost at that point because you have just "revealed your sources" to the controller which is against the point of Inverting control - you might as well just pass the Ninject `IKernel` to the controller.
- Anyway in your case, Ninject will only inject into the Controller **constructor** (assuming you have correctly wired it up) and in that respect, [Doug's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20387049/1362136) here is actually correct - if that `IMember` is some kind of *controller* dependency, then you must inject it into the constructor, and store it in for e.g. a private member so that you can later refer to it from within action methods.
- If the `IMember` is not a *controller* dependency but is instead just a model-bound parameter that you want passed to your controller, then Dependency Injection is not the answer - the parameter should be coming from the caller.

Also, there might be another problem even if you do end up using constructor injection.
The convention-based binding you are using requires that there is a single class called `Member` that implements `IMember`, i.e that the class name differs from the interface name only by lack of the initial "I". If this isn't the case for your class, then the convention-based binding will not work anyway and you need to use something explicit like

`kernel.Bind<IMember>.To<MyMemberImplementationClassName>();`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is your RegisterServices method in the NinjectWebCommon.cs file located in the App_Start folder?

You'll also need to pass the Member object into the view kind of like below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMember _member;

    public HomeController(IMember member)
    {
        _member = member;
    }
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_member);
    }
}
```